# Compiler explorer allows multiple editors. Can the contents of one editor be #included in another editor?

Tags: c++, compiler-explorer, godbolt

Godbolt's Compiler Explorer allows the creation of additional editors.
Can the body of one editor be #included in another? Something similar to this? https://godbolt.org/z/vvzE9jrzq

Obviously this doesn't work, but is there a way to make this work?
Given the ease of creating additional editors, it seems like this should be a feature.

Comment: You might want to add this as an idea on [the Compiler Explorer issue tracker](https://github.com/compiler-explorer/compiler-explorer/issues) (it might even exists such an issue if you just search around there a little).

Comment: I saved both your files manually as test.cpp and test.h and loaded them through "load or save text" icon (the floppy icon). I no longer have the error you had originally but a new one when I try to execute. might want to try.